# Get Content-Length from multipart/form-data

Tags: java, forms, servlets, post, multipartform-data

I used this code to upload my file.

```
out.println("<html>");
out.println("<body>");
out.print("<form action=\"/upload\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">");
out.print("<input name=\"file\" type=\"file\" size=\"50\">");
out.print("<input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">");
out.print("</form>");
out.println("</body>");
out.println("</html>");
```

However, I can only get this information by using `InputStream wholeContent = request.getInputStream();`. I wanna get the content-length(if I can get file-size, it would be better). How can I do this?

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryNAHFVP37tCcjHi8j
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

text-content here!

------WebKitFormBoundaryNAHFVP37tCcjHi8j
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

submit
------WebKitFormBoundaryNAHFVP37tCcjHi8j--
```